# currency doesn't appear with items

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

I have tow website.One of them has problem with currency that is doesn't appear with some item in [homepage](http://cl.ly/image/3D262H0u2l05)  and shopping [cart](http://cl.ly/image/2n17342Q0K2m) 
Any body can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the template file that if there is currency symbol define in the price template which you are using for homepage or cart page.

If its not then you can call the current currency symbol with below piece of code.

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

Comment: Sorry but where can i find the price template.

Comment: use the Template Path Hints tool to find out the exact template file path.

Comment: Hi. I think every thing is ok. http://cl.ly/code/2M3F2t3Z0610 ... http://cl.ly/code/2c413j3t0q3e  . Where is error. You have to know that i have 2 website the problem only on the first website and the currency doesn't appearing in cart when i checkout.

Comment: add me on skype: amalik62 , then i'll into your issue by my self.